# Error al ejecutar ejemplo de deno estando instalado correctamente

Tags: typescript, deno, runtime

llevo usando un tiempo deno sin problema pero desde hace un par de días no funciona bien ni con comandos como deno init ni otros similares, por ejemplo si trato de usar el ejemplo tipìco de hello world

```html
deno run https://examples.deno.land/hello-world.ts
```

me sale este error:

```
Could not initialize cache database 'C:\Users\jgcar\AppData\Local\deno\dep_analysis_cache_v1', deleting and retrying... (disk I/O error

Caused by:
    Error code 778: Error writing to disk)
Failed to open cache file 'C:\Users\jgcar\AppData\Local\deno\dep_analysis_cache_v1', opening in-memory cache.
Could not initialize cache database 'C:\Users\jgcar\AppData\Local\deno\node_analysis_cache_v1', deleting and retrying... (disk I/O error

Caused by:
    Error code 778: Error writing to disk)
Failed to open cache file 'C:\Users\jgcar\AppData\Local\deno\node_analysis_cache_v1', opening in-memory cache.
error: Module not found "https://examples.deno.land/hello-world.ts".
```